# how to update and insert into log table same time

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have tables like

**Solarwind**

```
App Name    ISStatus
WP1000  Mohan   Y
SP1000  Rohan   Y
```

**Solar**

```
SolarApp    Name    ISStatus
SP1000      Rohan   Y
```

wind

```
WindApp Name    ISStatus
WP1000  mohan   Y
```

i need to update the data of solar and wind if Appname matches  the table like 
WP1000 matches with wind table then i need to update Isstatus = 'N' 
and
SP1000 matches with solar table then i need to update Isstatus = 'N'
otherwise nothing will update
mean while I have log table i need to insert all the solar and winds table data which have updated like

```
logId appname name ISstatus
1      SP1000 Mohan Y
2      WP1000 Rohan Y
```

can you suggest what is the best way to do

Comment: If you only want to insert into a log table whenever you update a table then you could use [Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

Comment: is there any other way apart from triggers @JohnOdom

Comment: Not that I know of judging from my understanding of your question. All you want to do is insert into a log table only if you updated any of the tables, correct?

Comment: yes @JohnOdom if any of the table got updated record should inserted into log table

Comment: Assuming you're on SQL-Server 2008+ you could use change data capture/change data tracking and a service broker to seed the log table -- but a trigger is much much simpler to implement and maintain.

Comment: Well creating triggers sounds like it will help since you can create an after update trigger which you can use to check if the table has been updated, and if so insert into the log table. Unless you have something against the use of triggers?

Comment: i just don't want to use triggers i need to through other way suggest me the best way

Comment: I believe you could modify your query to use MERGE. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: "i just don't want to use triggers". Why? This is the simplest way to ensure every update wold be written to the log table...

Answer (score 1):

As of SQL server 2005 you can use the 'output to' clause of the sql statement.
After creating the table LOG you can:

```
UPDATE Solar SET ISSStatus ='N' WHERE Solarapp = 'SP1000'
OUTPUT inserted.appname, inserted.name, deleted.ISSstatus INTO LOG(appname, name,issstatus)

UPDATE Wind SET ISSStatus ='N' WHERE Windapp = 'WP1000'
OUTPUT inserted.appname, inserted.name, deleted.ISSstatus INTO LOG(appname, name,issstatus)
```

or you could output the results into a temporary table and merge the outputted records into another table. In this case this extra step seems not neccessary.